# Subversion checkout doesn't create working copy

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn, command-prompt, sharpsvn

On the command line I ran:

```
svn checkout --depth infinity "RepoURL"
```

It creates the directory matching the repo folder with all the same files but it is not a working copy. Right-clicking on it with TortoiseSVN gives a SVN upgrade working copy option and nothing else such as commit or update. If I try the same checkout with TortoiseSVN, it works fine and produces a working copy, green icon and all. I tried running `svn upgrade` in this new directory on the command line but that didn't change anything. I also tried a normal checkout using SharpSVN and c# by running `SvnClient.Checkout` and I had the same issue.

I have Subversion 1.7.18 and TortoiseSVN 1.7.15.

Comment: do `svn --version` from the command line... in other words, are you sure you are using 1.7 for both? Everything needs to match!

Comment: In other words, Tortoise SVN would not show "Upgrade" if it was *not* a working copy which means your command line tools and SharpSVN are using an older working copy format (which means an older version such as 1.6). If you tell TortoiseSVN to do the upgrade instead of trying with command line tools, I would bet that the command line tools will stop working.

Comment: I don't know what you did wrong, but I just created a new folder (`TempProj`), cd'd into that folder (`cd TempProj`), and ran `svn co file:///E:/Repos/MyRealProj .` (notice the dot at the end, which means *the current directory*). SVN checked out all of the files into that folder, creating a working copy. Opening the folder in Windows Explorer shows all of the files with the TSVN green overlay image. Right-clicking on the folder itself shows me the entire TSVN menu, as well as the SVN Update and SVN Commit items above it.

Comment: Which SharpSvn version did you use?

Comment: So version matching was the problem. I was using SharpSVN 1.8 and subversion 1.8. I downgraded them to match the repo version at 1.7.18 and it worked. Now, what do I mark as answer?

Answer (score 0):

You might be pulling files defining the local project enviroment variables that's not same as your local env. - Show us the problem with your non functional project! this is too vague